# Convert all urls in a string to anchors

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing, hyperlink

I have a string (`$string` for this example) and I want to do the following:

Parse the string and convert all urls within it to "actual links" (adding the open/close anchor tag).

What is the best way to do this?  I tried using `preg_split()` to create an array of the links contained in the string, with the idea of using `str_replace()` after the fact to make the changes.  This approach isn't working however because I am having a hard time isolating the links in the string of text with `preg_split()`.

`$string` could contain several links within it so that's why I was going with this approach.  If I knew precisely what the links were ahead of time or if `str_replace()` worked with pattern matching I would be set.

In short, I don't think the approach described above is the best way to go.  What is a better method?

Comment: In addition to my answer below, if you give some examples of strings that you're looking to split, I can give you some more specific help with the regex.

Comment: I am having some major problems finding a regex that will pick up all the URLS: Example: http://www.lasvegassun.com/blogs/ralstons-flash /2009/feb/17/caucus-within-gop-assembly-caucus ----get-out-your-/ it breads before the -flash. '@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@' = regex

Comment: @NicholasKreidberg your commented sample string should be included in the question as an edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is precisely the kind of thing `preg_replace` was intended for...

```
preg_replace('/your URL regex/', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $string);
```

*EDIT*: whaddya know, top Google hit for "URL regex PHP": http://snipplr.com/view/2371/regex-regular-expression-to-match-a-url/

```
# PHP Example: Automatically link URL's inside text.

$text = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
```

Note that if you want to match URLs in full generality, you'll need a devilishly complicated regular expression, but to match most common HTTP/HTTPS URLs, the above regex should work.

Comment: Absolutely perfect David, I was making this much more complicated than it needed to be.  Thank you.

Comment: Trying to come up with a regex that accomodates urls like: http://www.lasvegassun.com/blogs/ralstons-flash /2009/feb/17/caucus-within-gop-assembly-caucus ----get-out-your-/ -- it breaks at the "-flash"

Comment: Figuring out the right regex to match URLs probably deserves a question of its own (and it may have been asked already)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of `preg_split()`. It's used to split a string apart based on a regex. For example if you have a data string "one1two2three3four" you could use `preg_split` with a regex of "\d" and you'd get a 4-element array returned, consisting of "one", "two", "three", "four".

So unless the links are always separated by specific characters, `preg_split()` isn't the right tool for the job. You'll probably want to use `preg_match()` and then loop over the different matches that are returned.

Edit: or as David stated, `preg_replace()` is even better than `preg_match()`.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression depends on how the links will appear, or where they can appear (within quotes, inside a custom HTML Tag, etc).

It also depends on where the input is coming from. If it is coming from a user, it might be a better idea to use a markdown-like syntax.

At any rate, check out: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=links for some regular expressions that claim to match URIs and such. You would then use (originally posted by David):

```
preg_replace('/your URL regex/', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $string);
```